# Ubuntu 20.04 change default settings for all new users

Tags: user-management, gsettings

I'm trying to find a way to change default settings for all new users, for example the applications in dock, desktop icons, default homepage, etc...

Using dconf, extensions, and tweaks, I've setted a perfect configuration for my profile but if I log with another new user he has the standard defaults.

Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: Did you keep track of the changes you made? If so, do them again for the new user. If not, reinvent.